# Robot can't reach goal and keep rotate endless

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have some trouble implementing the navigation stack for one omnidirectional robot. The transfornation -and Odom publisher are done and work fine. I have read  [Navigation Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials) and i have adjusted my files so that the application could operate without a static map. So when I launched my files and start sending a goal, the robot rotate endless.

Has anyone an idea about this issue?   Here ist my setup for the navigation Stack:

Base local planner:

```
  TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 50
  min_vel_x: 10
  max_rotational_vel: 0.1
  min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.1

  acc_lim_theta: 0.6
  acc_lim_x: 2.5
  acc_lim_y: 2.5

  holonomic_robot: true

  meter_scoring: true
```

Coastmap common:

```
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
footprint: [ [0.37, 0.33], [-0.37, 0.33], [-0.37, -0.33], [0.37, -0.33] ]
#footprint_padding: 0.01
inflation_radius: 0.55

observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor

laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: /base_laser_front_link, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan_front, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

Global coastmap:

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 0.4
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 3.0
  height: 3.0
  resolution: 0.005
  origin_x: -1.5
  origin_y: -1.5
```

Local coastmap:

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 0.4
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 3.0
  height: 3.0
  resolution: 0.01
  origin_x: -1.5
  origin_y: -1.5
```

Move base:

```
<launch>

<node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" >
        <remap from="scan" to="scan_front" />
        <param name="map_update_interval" value="0.2" />
</node>

  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen"> 
    <param name="controller_frequency" value="0.8"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find miagy_2dnav)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find miagy_2dnav)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find miagy_2dnav)/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find miagy_2dnav)/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find miagy_2dnav)/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

Source file to send a goal:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <move_base_msgs/MoveBaseAction.h>
#include <actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h>

typedef actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction> MoveBaseClient;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "simple_navigation_goals");

  //tell the action client that we want to spin a thread by default
  MoveBaseClient ac("move_base", true);

  //wait for the action server to come up
  while(!ac.waitForServer(ros::Duration(5.0))){
    ROS_INFO("Waiting for the move_base action server to come up");
  }

  move_base_msgs::MoveBaseGoal goal;

  //we'll send a goal to the robot to move 1 meter forward
  goal.target_pose.header.frame_id = "base_link";
  goal.target_pose.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();

  goal.target_pose.pose.position.x = 1.0;
  goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;

  ROS_INFO("Sending goal");
  ac.sendGoal(goal);

  ac.waitForResult();

  if(ac.getState() == actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState::SUCCEEDED)
    ROS_INFO("Hooray, the base moved 1 meter forward");
  else
    ROS_INFO("The base failed to move forward 1 meter for some reason");

  return 0;
}
```

Any help will be appreciate.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211188/robot-can%27t-reach-goal-and-keep-rotate-endless/) by [Lil Kmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/20079/lil-kmer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-06-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [czhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/23566/czhang/) on 2015-08-13**:
I have exactly the same problem with the navigation stack. Did you solve it? Thanks.

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-06-02**:
Me too. If you have found a solution...

**Comment by [quentin](https://answers.ros.org/users/24914/quentin/) on 2016-09-02**:
same here...

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-09-02**:
Are you sure you want max_vel_x = 50 and min_vel_x = 10?  These are in meters per second so 10 m/s is approximately 22 mph or 36 km/h.  Also, your global resolution is 0.005 m which is just 5mm.  Is your odometry that accurate?  Finally, why do you set the controller_frequency so low (0.8 Hz)?

**Comment by [dottant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20666/dottant/) on 2016-10-25**:
same problem here. Solutions???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

In my case, the robot was rotating for ever without starting the navigation (even though the global path was computed and drawn on rviz). The reason for this behavior was a too small maximum translational acceleration: it was basically not sufficient to start the motion!! I just increased it and it worked

---

Originally posted by [quentin](https://answers.ros.org/users/24914/quentin/) with karma: 123 on 2016-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0